# Python postgres output formatting

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm using psycopg2 and I'd like to know if there's a way to generate some cleaner output from my SELECT statements.

My data looks like this in the database:

```
("Apple" user:(Apple) tag:(Apple))
```

When I pull the data down through psycopg2, it looks like this:

```
('("Apple" user:(Apple) tag:(Apple))')
```

I'd like it to not append those characters to the front and end of each row, is there a cleaner method to do it? Code follows.

```
cur.execute(''' 
    select field from table;
    ''')

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
     # Write rows to text file
     writer.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: or writer.write(row[0][1:-1] + '\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could process the row before you write to file, for example:

```
for row in rows:
     # Write rows to text file
     user = row[0]
     tag = row[1]
     writer.write(user + ' ' + tag + '\n')
```